# Two language site in wordpress what i can do

Tags: wordpress

I want to create 2 language site in word press. I am pretty new in word press. so what can i do. I will have 2 different theme for each language or do something else. The English is for left to right while Arabic is for right to left. So what can i do. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into the [WPML plugin](https://wpml.org/). Also, any time you emit a string from your own PHP code, you'll want to use the PHP [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) method, which makes the string localizeable and will allow you to localize it using WPML.

You may also want to modify your WordPress theme to emit the appropriate [`dir`](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir) tag depending on the language.

Comment: what about my them. i will have two them one for Arabic and one for English or what?

Comment: You will develop the site in one language, then localize/translate it into the other.

Comment: One site... alternate language strings in the database for additional languages.